# Is there any way to change coordinate mode of any Huion graphic tablets on a windows computer?

Tags: tablet, drawing

Changing the coordinate mode from absolute positioning to relative is quite common in all graphic tablets. And even my huion h610 pro had this option on a mac. But I moved to windows and it doesn't seem to have this option in Windows.

A lot of users have been encountering this issue online and not a lot of answers - albeit one was told that the option is not available on windows by a Huion rep. I find it hard to believe since that option is available even on linux and is intrinsic to how a graphic tablet works. Hopefully, someone who managed to find an answer can help avoid sending the tablet back.

Also, personally I think the tablet is fine , its just a case of finding the right drivers to work with windows 7 since I found the relative/absolute mouse positioning to be working fine in my macbook but not on my windows 7.

Comment: was hoping the design people might have found a way around this as they use huion tablets daily and since no one on the internet, not even huion themselves, seem to have a clue.

Comment: but this is more a design related question than it is IT? IT people dont use graphic tablets.

Answer (score 2):

I'm intrigued by the question, because I also own the Huion H610Pro. (and I didn't know about the relative/absolute behavior!) [Windows 8.1 x64]
I looked around the Net, and found nothing too. But I found your question in DeviantArt too (Creativ9? :')

Try this:

1. **Close the tablet driver** (its icon in the systemtray: rightclick> EXIT)
2. Go to **C:\Program Files\TabletDriver**. That's Huion's driver
   location.
3. **Back up tabletconfig.ini**
4. Open **tabletconfig.ini** with your text editing program (Notepad,
   etc.)
5. See line "**SimlateMouse=1**"
6. Change 1 to 0 (zero).
7. Save it! =')
8. If you can't save it, Google how to unlock system files so you can
   edit and save it :')
9. Unlock it... open, edit,.... then save it! =')

*Some beautiful screenshots:*

[image: Config file, with "SimlateMouse" line]

//

[image: "Simulate Mouse" is checked, but greyed out]

Now, check if the behavior has changed =')

[image: "Simulate Mouse" is now unchecked!]

**ADD:** make a shortcut link of that config file in your desktop or what's convenient for you. Tadaaa =')

Comment: It didnt work for me. See the problem is that if the .ini file has SimulateMouse = 0, and then when I open TabletDriver, its SimulateMouse setting gets changed to unchecked, ie 0, and the pen can not move the mouse on the screen at all. When I check it again, then the pen can move the cursor on the screen.

Comment: Also my GUI is different to yours and I downloaded the drivers from huion website today. i.imgur.com/WdcMuf6.png

Notice the option to check/uncheck SimulateMouse. When I uncheck it, pen cant move cursor on screen at all, and changing ini to 0 has that effect. Ini atumatically uncheck the SimulateMouse in GUI next time I restart TabletDriver if ini has setting set to 0.

Comment: :'/ Sorry. I couldn't check it on my side first. My Huion is in the office. Sorry I wasn't able to help too. Now I don't know if I should delete my answer or keep it here as a wrong answer.

Comment: its not a wrong answer and I am grateful. But our softwares/drivers/GUI seem different so this answer may be useful to someone else. In fact, I dont understand why your gui is different to mine when we both have same model and downloaded from their website.

Comment: Thanks man, I appreciate that =') Well, I do hope it helps someone else. I'll try it also on mine. --Maybe the GUI is different depending on the system? I have WIndows 8.1 (pre-installed), so that may be why. Huion isn't very good at drivers and driver updates (based on what I've read in the Internet :'o) so the drivers are different depending on the Windows OS.